# Send Logging not working on Sandbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, logging

We are trying to log sends in a Send Log DE in Sandbox SFMC BU, but the data is not getting populated.

Does Send Logging works in Sandbox?

Thanks,
Sanchit

Comment: Was the Send Log DE created with the Data Extension Template? Do you have Enterprise Send Logging turned on where sends from this BU might be being logged to the Admin BU's Send Log DE?

Answer (score 2):

Send Logging works in Sandbox accounts.  You should verify that there aren't any other active SendLog Data Extensions in the Business Unit, and/or that your account is not setup to log everything the the Enterprise account SendLog. As well as, that the Data Extension you are using is built from the SendLog Data Extension template.